# jQuery click function, wait for it to complete before starting again?

Tags: jquery

At the moment when I double/treble/etc click on the .next button the script is ran, I need it to queue after each other? How can I do this so that the function is completed before starting again?

HTML

```
<ul id="one" class="first selected">
   <li class="pic_one"></li>
   <li class="pic_two"></li>
   <li class="pic_three"></li>                       
</ul>
<ul id="two">
   <li class="pic_one"></li>
   <li class="pic_two"></li>
   <li class="pic_three"></li>                        
</ul>
<ul id="three" class="last">
   <li class="pic_one"></li>
   <li class="pic_two"></li>
   <li class="pic_three"></li>                        
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.slider .next').click(function(){
   if($('.slider ul.selected').hasClass('last')){
      // leave blank
   } else {
      $('.slider ul.selected').hide('slide', { direction: "left" }, 1000);  
      $('.slider ul.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $('.slider ul').parent().next('ul').show('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000).addClass('selected'); 
   }
});
```

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: So would you like it to be clickable all the time, and just queue the animations indefinetely, or just disable the click function until the animatons have completed?

Comment: unbind, then rebind the click event in the callback.

Comment: I think I'd like it to just disable the click function until it's completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Rory's answer, but using the :animated pseudoselector. This prevents the click event from being processed while the element is being animated.

```
$('.slider .next').click(function(){
   if($('.slider ul.selected').is(':animated')) return;

   if($('.slider ul.selected').hasClass('last')){
      // leave blank
   } else {
      $('.slider ul.selected').hide('slide', { direction: "left" }, 1000);  
      $('.slider ul.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $('.slider ul').parent().next('ul').show('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000).addClass('selected'); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly...you're just trying to prevent animations from stacking on multiple clicks. Use `.stop()` BEFORE calling your next animation.

Example:

```
$('.slider .next').click(function(){
   if($('.slider ul.selected').hasClass('last')){
      // leave blank
   } else {
      $('.slider ul.selected').stop().hide('slide', { direction: "left" }, 1000);  
      $('.slider ul.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $('.slider ul').parent().next('ul').stop().show('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000).addClass('selected'); 
   }
});
```